# Android 2.3 Sqlite Troubles with while inserting

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I've a straight forward question, I think I'm missing some point. My test app is being deployed on emulator, within an AVD with a virtual SD Card of 30megs.
When I call the following from my main activity:

```
DatabaseManager.Initialize(this);
DatabaseManager.getEntities();
```

My app crashes and debugger says no such table ! The table **ITEM** is created in the onCreate() of my database helper and **is** correctly called (Step by step debug). What am I missing there ?

**database manager**

```
public class DatabaseManager {

public static final String ITEM_CONTACT = "CONT";
public static final String ITEM_FILE = "FILE";
public static final String ITEM_APP = "AAPP";
public static final String ITEM_OPT = "OPTS";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "androfast.sqlite3.db";
private static final Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_ITEM = "ITEM";
private static final String TABLE_KEYWORD = "KEYWORD";

private static final String DATABASE_SCHEMA_FILE = "schema.sql";

public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_PACKAGE = "pkg";
public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_TYPE = "kind";
public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_PRIORITY = "karma";

public static final String KEYWORD_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String KEYWORD_COLUMN_VALUE = "word";
public static final String KEYWORD_COLUMN_PRIORITY = "karma";

private static SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;
private static DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private static Context context;

public static void Initialize(Context ctx) throws IOException{
    context = ctx;
    InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_SCHEMA_FILE);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder("");

    String s;

    while ((s = r.readLine()) != null){
        strQuery.append(s);
    }
    r.close();

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION, strQuery.toString());
    dbSqlite = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public static SQLiteDatabase getSqliteDatabase(){
    return dbSqlite;
}

public static void runQuery(String strQuery){
    dbSqlite.execSQL(strQuery);
}

public static List<Item> getEntities(){
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Cursor cursor;

    dbSqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO ITEM (name, pkg, kind) VALUES('Don Coreleone', 'life.thug.jail', 'CONT')");
    dbSqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO ITEM (name, pkg, kind) VALUES('slavery.png', 'life.thug.jail', 'FILE')");
    dbSqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO ITEM (name, pkg, kind) VALUES('Alcatraz', 'life.thug.jail', 'AAPP')");
    dbSqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO ITEM (name, pkg, kind) VALUES('BLUETOOTH', 'life.thug.jail', 'OPTS')");
    dbSqlite.execSQL("INSERT INTO ITEM (name, pkg, kind) VALUES('Che Guevara', 'life.thug.jail', 'CONT')");

    cursor = dbSqlite.query(TABLE_ITEM, null,null,null,null,null,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Log.d("APP/DB", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ITEM_COLUMN_NAME)));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();

    return items;
}

}
```

**database helper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final String LOG_TAG = "SQLiteOpenHelper";
private String dbCreateQuery;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, String dbCreate) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    dbCreateQuery = dbCreate;
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    return super.getWritableDatabase();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    return super.getReadableDatabase();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

@Override
public void close() {
    super.close();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(dbCreateQuery);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"Upgrading database from version " + i + " to version " + i1);
    // No need to do drops of tables, these must be included in the schema.sql file
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
}
}
```

Thanks for your directions fellas

Kind regards,

Miloud B.

Comment: The contents of androfast.sqlite3.db would be interesting... can you paste? You know that onCreate() is only called once, right? Try clearing your data directory (via App settings) and running it again. Finally, as a seperate observation, you should do this much hard work on an AsyncTask, not on the UI thread...

Comment: I tried cleaning data, and actually I just discovered something else... my onCreate is never called :| and I'm a 100% sure it was called last time...

Comment: Miloud, have you tried viewing the contents of your database via sqlite3 command in the adb shell?  This has helped me debug problems like this.  see: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite

Comment: On Linux i'd have known how to do this. I'm not used to windows at all :) I'll try to figure out how I could do that. Thanks

By the way, onCreate is called correctly :P

Comment: @Miloud: FYI: `onCreate` will only be called if the database doesn't exist (or its version is older than the one you passed into your constructor). It's *expected behaviour* that `onCreate` is not called each time.

Comment: Guys, I did it. I noticed issues though:

A- My database has only the first table, my SQL create db statements are read from an asset (text file). This file has like: 

Create database X(...); Create database Y(...); 

So it seems only X is created, does it stop after the first ";" ?

By the way, X is still the table I'm using afterward in my INSERT :)

Comment: yeah I know onCreate is called once. And I just noticed something, onCreate sometimes isn't called (database is deleted through adb shell)... which is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue !

All is in the following statement:

*public void execSQL (String sql)

Since: API Level 1
Execute a **single** SQL statement that is not a query. For example, CREATE TABLE, DELETE, INSERT, etc. **Multiple statements separated by semicolons** are **not supported**. Takes a write lock*